# Custom license for WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, licensing

I am developer and I have a plugin.
My plugin is free for everyone ( everyone can download it from WordPress plugins repository). But I need to add only one restrictions to my plugin license:

1. I don't want that any user or developer will put his credits on my plugin.

Wich license I have to use for this? GPL? GPL 2? There is so many license types.... How can I implement this "feature"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is impossible, while keeping plugin GPL-compatible (which is considered cultural norm for WP extensions, legal claims aside for now).

Much of open source licensing in general is to accommodate concept of *derivative* work. That is for it to really be open source other should be allowed to change it. If they change it then it's their work now *however* in many licenses *original work* still needs to be credited of course.

What you seem to want is license that is "free as in beer" but *not* open source.

I can't recommend one form the top of my head, but you might find some searching for free/freeware licenses.

Do note the point on GPL incompatibility. That *will* bar your plugin from being hosted in official WP repository (if you want to) and is rather easy way to get a mountain of negative feedback.

And if someone wants to pass your work as their work... will the license really ever stop them?

Comment: @JackJohansson What does that question have to do with this? SMH Explain why it's not the proper way to do it. This answer is correct IMO.

Comment: @JackJohansson You're right, it's definitely not the proper way to do it. This will be viewed as spamming other threads. You should keep that conversation within the relevant thread.